# QPainter with shared QOpenGLContext in QThread - seg faulting on nouveau

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm trying to learn how to do threaded gl with Qt for the purpose of offloading a lot of QPainter draws in a separate thread.  I have a QGLWidget in the main gui thread drawing some lines from a vbo and displaying a texture.  In the QGLWidget's initializeGL() function, I create a QOffscreenSurface, QOpenGLContext and a QThread and then move the QOpenGLContext to the new QThread.  The GLWidget's context and the QOpenGLContext are set as sharing.  The QThread is started, it creates a QGLFramebufferObject as a paint device for a QPainter.  When the QPainter is finished, the threat emits a signal to the QGLWidget to redraw with the finished texture from the fbo.

On the nvidia open source nouveau driver on Kubuntu 14.04 machine, if many draws are made, the program seg faults and can puke out video driver stuff. If few draws are made using the QPainter, all is well.  Seems fine on a Nexus 4, Kubuntu 14.04 Intel 2nd Generation Core and Intel 82945G/GZ Kubuntu 14.04.  I suspect the nouveau is just less tolerance of my unknown mistake?

```
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Invalid argument
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 3 bufs 12 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000<\br>
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000001 00000013 00000002 00000000 00000002
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000002 00000016 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000003 00000007 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000004 0000000a 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000005 0000000b 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000006 00000008 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000007 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000008 00000003 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000009 0000000e 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 0000000a 00000017 00000002 00000000 00000002
nouveau: ch0: buf 0000000b 00000018 00000002 00000000 00000002
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

test.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets opengl

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES = main.cpp textThread.cpp
HEADERS = main.h textThread.h
```

main.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QGLShader>
#include <QTimer>
#include "textThread.h"

class glview : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit glview(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~glview();
    QSize sizeHint() const;

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    QTimer repaintTimer;
    QGLShaderProgram *program, *txtovlp;
    textThread *maketext;
    quint32 vbo_id[2];

private slots:
    void repaint(void);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "main.h"

struct vrtx {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
}__attribute__((packed)) line_geo[] = {
//   x, y, z, r, g, b
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
};

struct txtr_vrtx {
    GLfloat   x;
    GLfloat   y;
    GLfloat   z;
    GLfloat   tx;
    GLfloat   ty;
}__attribute__((packed)) txtr_geo[] = {
//   x, y, z, tx,ty
    {3, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {3, 2, 0, 0, 1},
    {4, 2, 0, 1, 1},
    {4, 1, 0, 1, 0},
};

glview::glview(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    connect(&repaintTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(repaint()));
    repaintTimer.start(20);
}

glview::~glview()
{
    delete maketext->context;
    delete maketext->offscrnsf;
    delete maketext;
    delete program;
    delete txtovlp;
}

QSize glview::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(500, 300);
}

void glview::initializeGL()
{
    initializeGLFunctions();
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);

    QGLShader *vshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex, this);
    const char *vsrc =
        "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
        "attribute mediump vec4 colour;\n"
        "varying mediump vec4 f_colour;\n"
        "uniform mediump mat4 matrix;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
        "    f_colour = colour;\n"
        "}\n";
    vshader->compileSourceCode(vsrc);

    QGLShader *fshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment, this);
    const char *fsrc =
        "varying mediump vec4 f_colour;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = f_colour;\n"
        "}\n";
    fshader->compileSourceCode(fsrc);

    program = new QGLShaderProgram(this);
    program->addShader(vshader);
    program->addShader(fshader);
    program->link();

    QGLShader *txtovlp_vshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex, this);
    const char *txtovlp_vsrc =
        "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
        "attribute mediump vec2 texCoord;\n"
        "varying mediump vec2 texc;\n"
        "uniform mediump mat4 matrix;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
        "    texc = texCoord;\n"
        "}\n";
    txtovlp_vshader->compileSourceCode(txtovlp_vsrc);

    QGLShader *txtovlp_fshader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment, this);
    const char *txtovlp_fsrc =
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
        "varying mediump vec2 texc;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texc.st);\n"
        "}\n";
    txtovlp_fshader->compileSourceCode(txtovlp_fsrc);

    txtovlp = new QGLShaderProgram(this);
    txtovlp->addShader(txtovlp_vshader);
    txtovlp->addShader(txtovlp_fshader);
    txtovlp->link();

    glGenBuffers(2, vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(line_geo), line_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(txtr_geo), txtr_geo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    doneCurrent();

    maketext = new textThread;
    maketext->offscrnsf = new QOffscreenSurface();
    maketext->offscrnsf->create();
    if (!maketext->offscrnsf->isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "Surface Failed";
        exit(1);
    }

    maketext->context = new QOpenGLContext();
    maketext->context->setShareContext(this->context()->contextHandle());
    maketext->context->create();
    if (!maketext->context->isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "Context Failed";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!maketext->context->areSharing(this->context()->contextHandle(), maketext->context)) {
        qDebug() << "Sharing Failed";
        exit(1);
    }
    maketext->context->moveToThread(maketext);

    //connect(maketext, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(repaint()));
    connect(maketext, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(repaint()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    maketext->start();
}

void glview::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    makeCurrent();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void glview::repaint(void)
{
    repaintTimer.start(20);
    updateGL();
}

void glview::paintGL()
{
    static quint32 i;

    i++;

    printf("Pa");
    makeCurrent();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.ortho(0, 5, 0, 3, -1, 1);

    program->bind();
    program->setUniformValue("matrix", matrix);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[0]);
    int vertexLocation = program->attributeLocation("vertex");
    program->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct vrtx), 0);

    int colourLocation = program->attributeLocation("colour");
    program->enableAttributeArray(colourLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colourLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 12));

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, sizeof(line_geo) / sizeof(struct vrtx));

    txtovlp->bind();
    txtovlp->setUniformValue("matrix", matrix);

    maketext->textLock.lock();
    if (maketext->done) {
        maketext->textLock.unlock();
        //qDebug() << "Painting with text" << i;
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id[1]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, maketext->texture_id);

        int txtr_vertexLocation = txtovlp->attributeLocation("vertex");
        txtovlp->enableAttributeArray(txtr_vertexLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(txtr_vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), 0);

        int texCoordLocation = txtovlp->attributeLocation("texCoord");
        txtovlp->enableAttributeArray(texCoordLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct txtr_vrtx), ((char*)NULL + 12));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    }
    else {
        maketext->textLock.unlock();
        //qDebug() << "Painting" << i;
    }

    glFlush();
    printf("int\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_X11InitThreads);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    glview widget;
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

textThread.h

```
#ifndef textThread_h
#define textThread_h

#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QFont>
#include <QDebug>

class textThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    textThread();
    ~textThread();
    QMutex textLock;
    QOffscreenSurface *offscrnsf;
    QOpenGLContext *context;
    bool done;
    quint32 texture_id;

signals:
    void finished(void);

protected:
    void run();

private:
    QGLFramebufferObject *fbo;
    QFont font;
};

#endif
```

textThread.cpp

```
#include <QPainter>
#include "textThread.h"

#define QPAINT_A_LOT

textThread::textThread()
{
    done = 0;
    fbo = NULL;
    font.setFamily("Helvetica");
}

textThread::~textThread()
{
    delete fbo;
}

void textThread::run()
{
    context->makeCurrent(offscrnsf);
    qDebug() << "Thread";

    if (!fbo)
        fbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(100, 100, GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    fbo->bind();
    texture_id = fbo->texture();

    QPainter painter(fbo);
    font.setPointSize(20);
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.eraseRect(0,0,100,100);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
#ifdef  QPAINT_A_LOT
    quint32 i;
    for (i=0; i<140000; i++) {
        //if (!(i%32768))
        if (!(i%1024))
            qDebug() << i;
        painter.drawText(0, 60, "FBO");
    }
#else
    painter.drawText(0, 60, "FBO");
    sleep(1);
#endif
    painter.end();
    fbo->release();

    context->doneCurrent();
    textLock.lock();
    done = 1;
    textLock.unlock();
    emit finished();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I switch to the closed source nvidia driver on the same machine that this code seg faults on  and it works fine.  I also tried it on windows and it is fine.  I'm pretty sure the issue is the open source nouveau driver.